# Why am i receiving none as the output

Tags: python

I was trying to return all the names given into an alphabetically ordered list but it keeps returning none instead.

```
#FirstAndLast

#variables
#prompt = str (input("Please enter a name or say DONE to incdicate no more names to be input: "))
names = []

def main():
    LOOP = getLoop()
    CHECK_NAMES = getCheck()


def getLoop():
    prompt = str (input("Please enter a name or say DONE to incdicate no more names to be input: "))
    while prompt != 'DONE':
        names.append(prompt)
        prompt = str (input("Please enter a name or say DONE to incdicate no more names to be input: "))

def getCheck():
    if len(names) == 0:
        print("No names have been input")
    else:
        sortNames = names.sort()
        print(sortNames)

    

#calls main
main()
```

Comment: Because the function `main()` doesn't have a return value

Comment: `names.sort()` does not return anything. `print(names)` instead after calling `names.sort()`.

Comment: The big takeaway here is never assume what a function/method is going to return. If you aren't familiar or something opposite of your expectations is happening, just look up the function's documentation and it will tell you what it returns: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/sort.html#return-value